# How do I parse KLV data?

Tags: c++, metadata, mpeg2-ts

How do I parse KLV data? 
There is some codes below. I'd like to make a map using klv metadata. But how?

I know that the latitude and the longitude is in the 13th and 14th key in klv. But how could I use them and make a map.

```
ILMMpgDmx *CMainFrame::GetMPEG2DemuxInterface()
{
    IUnknown *pSplitter;
    HRESULT hr = m_player->GetSubObject(ltmmPlay_Object_Splitter, &pSplitter);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ILMMpgDmx *pMpgDmx;
        hr = pSplitter->QueryInterface(IID_ILMMpgDmx, (void **)&pMpgDmx);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            pSplitter->Release();
            return pMpgDmx;
        }
        pSplitter->Release();
    }
    return NULL;
}

void CMainFrame::EnableMPEG2DemuxCallback()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    ILMMpgDmx *pMpgDmx = GetMPEG2DemuxInterface();
    if (pMpgDmx)
    {
        // make sure the demux is not using the callback I am about to destroy
        pMpgDmx->put_CallbackObj(NULL);

        DeleteCallbackClass();

        m_pCallback = new CMPEG2DemuxCallback(pMpgDmx);

        // Force the callback to be called in the main thread. C++ applications in general can handle data in another thread, but our app is using MFC
        // Our callback will display data in a window and MFC doesn't work well when you use windows from threads other than the main thread
        // So, for simplicity, we will ask the demux to send the data to the main thread
        hr = pMpgDmx->put_CallInSameThread(VARIANT_TRUE);
        hr = pMpgDmx->put_CallbackObj(m_pCallback);

        pMpgDmx->Release();
    }
}
```

And the DataAvailable() function being called looks like this:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CMPEG2DemuxCallback::DataAvailable
( 
    /* [in] */ VARIANT *pData,
    /* [in] */ long lDataSize,
    /* [in] */ FileTypeConstants fileType,
    /* [in] */ long streamPID,
    /* [in] */ long streamType,
    /* [in] */ PTSTypeConstants PTSType,
    /* [in] */ double PTS,
    /* [in] */ long flags
)
{
    // skip small (most likely invalid) data chunks
    if(lDataSize <= 1)
        return S_OK;

    //refresh control
    { 
        static const DWORD MIN_REFRESH_TIME = 1000 ;//1 second
        static DWORD dwLastTime = 0 ;//allow first data to be displayed

        DWORD dwCurTime = GetTickCount ( ) ;

        if ( dwCurTime - dwLastTime < MIN_REFRESH_TIME )
        {         
            return S_OK ;
        }
        else
        {
            dwLastTime = dwCurTime ;
        }
    }

    CPrivateDataView* pDataView = CPrivateDataViewManager::GetPrivateDataListView ( ) ;

    if(!pDataView)
        return S_OK;//skip

    pDataView->SetRedraw ( FALSE ) ;
    pDataView->GetListCtrl ( ).DeleteAllItems ( ) ;

    {
        HRESULT hr;

        if(flags & DataFlag_IsKLV)
        {
            ILMKlvParser* pParser;

            hr = m_pMpgDmx->GetKlvParser(streamPID, &pParser);
            if(FAILED(hr))
                return hr;

            hr = EnumKlvKeys(pParser, pDataView, NULL, pData, lDataSize, flags);
            if(FAILED(hr)) 
            { 
                pParser->Release() ;

                return hr;
            }

            pParser->Release();
        }
        else if(flags & DataFlag_IsAscii)
        {
            CString str;

            hr = DumpVariantAsAscii(str, pData, lDataSize);
            if(FAILED(hr))
                return hr;

            pDataView->AddValue (str) ;
        }
        else if(flags & DataFlag_IsBinary)
        {
            CString str;

            hr = DumpVariantAsBinary(str, pData, lDataSize);
            if(FAILED(hr))
                return hr;

            pDataView->AddValue (str) ;
        }
        else
        {
            ASSERT ( FALSE ) ;      
            return E_UNEXPECTED;
        }
    }

    pDataView->SetRedraw ( TRUE ) ;
    pDataView->RedrawWindow ( ) ;

    return S_OK ;
}
```

These are all codes that I found. Also I found this klv library. I need a path for advicing.

https://github.com/Hunter522/libklv

Comment: Did you found solution how to solve KLV?

Comment: No, now I'm trying to solve how to get metadata from astreaming video. I think I should use directshow pins/filtres.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to parse KLV from MPEG2 TS.
i did the following
1. Use MPEg2- demux directshow filter that knows to parse the PID of metadata KLV.
2. i built my own directshow filter ( based on dump filter ) this filter accept in receive the entire PID of the KLV and than using the libklv  from here
https://github.com/Hunter522/libklv
i added into the filter and this gave me the key , length and values.

But here is the trick:
KLV meta data can be part of protocol so in my case the protocol is MISB 601.8
here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/MISB_Standard_0601.pdf

Every tag have its own formula, its units and name 
there are 70 + tags.
thats mean that if a tag have 2 byte , go to its tag index in the MISB and the formula is there.

Comment: Can you share your codes with me? because I'm trying for many months. ıt's for my school  project

Comment: I don't know how to get metadata in the stream for parsing. Firstly I should get data from the stream. But I couldn't be able to do this. can you share your contact too?

Comment: hededesedede (at) gmail.com

Comment: also I have created a form for showing in VS. thanks